# Conectar varias webs con las mismas apis de stripe

Tags: stripe

tengo 2 webs que quisiera conectar a mi cuenta de stripe, mi pregunta es con las mismas apis puedo conectar las 2?

Tendria que usar lo del oauth para poder redirigir o directamente lo mejor seria crear una cuenta de stripe para cada web?

Answer (score 0):

es posible utilizar las mismas APIs para ambas cuentas, pero de todas formas Stripe recomienda utilizar cuentas separadas para cada web.

Teniendo cuentas independientes lo hace más robusto y simple al momento de rotar claves, dar de baja la cuenta, etc. Además, al tener cuentas separadas podrás customizarlas de acuerdo a cada página web, para que los usuarios sepan a quién le están pagando.